# How to show specific user details in react native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am new in React Native what I am trying to do is to fetch details of user like for example I made a form in which I have added details of user and they are successfully stored in firebase db, now even I displayed all the information but here what I want to do is when user click on "Regional-Location" i.e Mexico that specific person details from mexico appears.
Here's what I have done: 
I have made a flatlist where I am displaying location:

```
<FlatList
 data={this.state.markers}
   renderItem={
       ({ item }) =>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { }}> //**Here onPress I want to show further details from firebase of specific user**
   <Text>{"Instructor Availibility: " + item.to}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                }
      style={{ width: '100%' }}
               />
```

[image: These are other values like name which on press I want to show of specific user]